# $\mathbb{R}[Q_8]$ is not a division algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra

Given the Quaternion group $$Q_8=\{\pm1,\pm i,\pm j,\pm k\}$$ with the product: $1$ is the unit, $-1$ commutes with all elements, $(-1)^2=1$ and $i^2=j^2=k^2=ijk=-1.$ The group ring $\mathbb{R}[Q_8]$ has dimension $8$ (as an algebra over $\mathbb{R}$). The elements of $Q_8$ all have multiplicative inverses. Why is this not a division algebra over $\mathbb{R}$?

The easy solution is: Such an division algebra has dimension $1$, $2$ or $4$ (theorem of Frobenius).

Can this be shown without using Frobeniu's theorem about division algebras ober the real numbers?

Comment: The group ring $\Bbb R Q_8$ is a little funky because, e.g. $-2(i)\neq 2(-i)$. I suspect this quirkiness might be useful in getting a contradiction.

Comment: What do you mean by $-2(i)$ as an element of $\mathbb{R}[Q_8]$?

Comment: But $\mathbb{R}$ consits of maps $Q_8\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$. What is the corresponding map?

Comment: $$f(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{ll} -2 & x=i \\ 0 & \text{else} \end{array}\right.$$

Comment: Okay, thank you. Do you know yet where the contradiction is?

Comment: No, I don't have any intention of working on this until I get my work done for today :)

Comment: I would recommend rephrasing the question, because it is confusing to have a group element labelled $-1$ that is not the additive inverse of $+1$ in $\Bbb{R}[\mathrm{Q}_8]$.  Perhaps try something like $\mathrm{Q}_8=\{e,\overline{e},i,\overline{i},j,\overline{j},k,\overline{k}\}$, so that each of the eight can be used as a basis element of the group ring.  We have that $-e\ne\overline{e}$.  To show what you want, you only have to show the existence of a nontrivial zero divisor.

Comment: Look at associativity

Comment: Why would associativity fail if it is a ring

Comment: Associativity wouldn't fail.  I was going to query the same.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1978912/group-algebra-ever-a-field for a nice and general way to see this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are extremely simple ways to see this.

You could observe that [group rings are almost never simple rings](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1978942/29335).

Another good thing for your toolbox for finite groups $G$ is that **if $G$ has a nontrivial normal subgroup, $\mathbb R[G]$ isn't even a domain.** The quaternion group has, to put it mildly, lots of normal subgroups.

To see this, note that the sum of elements in a finite nontrivial normal subgroup creates a nontrivial central idempotent that splits the ring in two pieces. If the normal subgroup $H$ had order $k$, then $\frac1k\sum_{h\in H}h$ is a central idempotent. Consequently $eR\oplus (1-e)R$ splits the ring into the product of two rings. Or more simply, $e(1-e)=0$ proves there are zero divisors.

This only relies on $|H|$ being a unit in the coefficient ring. There are still some related tricks to this in rings of positive characteristic, but it's more than sufficient already for this problem. If the order of the subgroup is a divisor of the characteristic of the ring, then the sum of the elements in the subgroup is nilpotent, and it is not a domain (or division ring) in that case either.

Comment: Let us look at your first point. So the idea is to see that there is a two-sided ideal in $\mathbb{R}[Q_8]$, which is not zero or equal to $\mathbb{R}[Q_8]$. Is we have this, $\mathbb{R}[Q_8]$ can't be a field since a field has only the two trivial ideals. So there are two questions left: #1 What is a possible ideal and #2 Why it is not a division algebra if it it not a field?

Comment: @user114179 a ring is called *simple* if it only has trivial ideals. Fields $\subseteq$ division rings  $\subseteq$ simple rings.  Therefore if it's not simple, it can't be a division ring either .

Comment: Yeah, but we are talking about division $\textit{algebras}$. But if it is not a division ring, it can't be a division algebra, right?

Comment: @user114179 By the definition in thinking of, a division algebra is *a priori* a division ring. Does your definition of division algebra not assume associativity?

Comment: It does. A ring is associative by definition. But what is the not trivial ideal we need?

Comment: @user114179 the ideal is explicitly explained in the link. Read, please.

Comment: @user114179 I am not handy with the functional definition of group rings, but yes, I trust you have accurately translated the idea to that language. The idea is that $g-1$ will map to $0$ for any nonidentity element $g$ of the group.